# How to create sign native DMG installer using AIR package

Tags: apache-flex, air

How to create signed native DMG installer from AIR package on MAC.
Using following command I am able to create signed native EXE installer for windows,

adt -package -target native -storetype pkcs12 -storepass PASSWORD -keystore comodo.pfx myApp.exe myApp.air

Now, I want to create signed DMG installer. I have done lot of research on this on internet still no luck.

I have used the 
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -storepass PASSWORD -keystore comodo.pfx -target native myApp.dmg myApp.air 
command on MAC but I am getting "not enough arguments" error.

Which arguments I am missing here?
Has anyone signed a native DMG installer for MAC using AIR package?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You have to do it on a OS X machine. You cannot generate a .dmg on Windows. More info inside first paragraph of Adobe AIR **Packaging a native installer instructions** (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html)